# CUDA toolkit in PGI Compilers is missing link.stub

Tags: c++, cuda, pgi

I am trying to build my CMake/CUDA project using the CUDA toolkit 9.0 that comes with the PGI compilers. Unfortunately, when I try to do so I get the following error when I run `cmake`:

```
/home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/9.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/usr/bin/g++-6
-shared -dlink CMakeFiles/cmTC_858b1.dir/main.cu.o -o
CMakeFiles/cmTC_858b1.dir/cmake_device_link.o

g++-6: error:
/home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/9.0/bin/crt/link.stub: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, such file does not exist in the above directory. However, if I go to the system's CUDA toolkit directory (`/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin`) which is  installed with `apt-get`, the directory `crt` with the file `link.stub` is there. If I just copy the `crt` directory from that location to the PGI CUDA toolkit directory, CMake stops complaining and everything compiles (well, I get a linker error regarding one of the `cuFFT`libraries but I think this is a completely different problem).

- What is the purpose of the `link.stub` file?
- Why it is not available in the CUDA toolkit that comes with the PGI Compilers?
- Is there a more "gentle" way to deal with this problem? I don't like the copy-paste solution because my system's CUDA toolkit version is 8.0, while the one in the PGI Compiler toolkit is 9.0.

I am using the PGI Compiler toolkit version 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (PGI) only ship the parts of the CUDA Toolkit that we need for compiling OpenACC and CUDA Fortran codes.  Our package is not intended for stand-alone CUDA C development.  For this, please download the full CUDA 9.0 Toolkit directly from NVIDIA https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads